# How to get MD5 of a file using base64 encoding of the file in js (for validating s3 upload)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, md5

I want to upload a file to s3 and if I understand correctly, s3 returns me the ETag for the file, which is basically md5 hash of the file I've uploaded. I want to check if it is same with my local hash to see if its uploaded correctly.

But I couldn't find a good example that uses base64 or the buffer of a file to get the md5 of a file

So far I have this:

```
const result = await s3.putObject({
    Bucket: lambdaConfig.s3BucketName, 
    Key: filePath,
    Body:new Buffer.from(fileBase64,'base64'),
    ContentType: mimeType,
    Metadata: {},
}).promise();

const localHash = // Turn fileBase64 to md5 hash
const remoteHash = JSON.parse(result.ETag);

if( remoteETag === localHash ) {
    // Success.
}
```

How can I get the localHash from fileBase64 ?

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the built-in [crypto API](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) to compute hashes in node.js.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
//...
const etag = crypto.createHash('md5');
// .update means to add to the buffer, you can call .update multiple times
etag.update(Buffer.from(fileBase64, 'base64'));
// .digest(encoding) gives you the computed value of buffer
const localHash = etag.digest('hex');
console.log(`localHash: ${localHash}`);
```

And as a tip, using `new` with `Buffer` is deprecated, see [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_array).